# Why do larger random matrices maximize their number of clusters with lower densities?

Tags: probability, descriptive-statistics

Consider a matrix whose elements are independently assigned a value $1$ with probability $p$ and a value $0$ with probability $1-p$.

Define a *cluster* of cells as a maximal connected component in the graph of cells with the value of $1$, where edges connect cells whose rows and columns both differ by at most $1$ (so up to eight neighbors for each cell).

I numerically plotted the number of clusters vs. the probability $p$, for matrices of size $8\times 8, 16 \times 16, 32 \times 32, 64 \times 64, 128 \times 128, 256 \times 256.$  The results came out like:

Plot: Number of clusters per unit area vs. probability p for different L's:
[image: Plot: Number of clusters per unit area vs. probability p for different L's]

**Questions:**

- **Why are the maxima further left for larger matrices — why do larger matrices achieve their highest expected numbers of clusters with smaller values of $p$?**
- Has there been any study or is it possible to derive a formula which takes in $p$, size of cluster and size of the matrix as input and outputs probability of that size of the cluster existing? And/or are there any interesting results regarding this?
- As we increase from $p$ from 0, we start with isolated $1$'s popping up as individual clusters in a matrix filled with $0$'s. As $p$ increases larger clusters tend to form. The  $p$ with the maximum number of clusters seems to occur when the joining of clusters overtakes the formation of new clusters. Is there any other way to explain the occurrence of the maxima which I'm missing? Are there other noteworthy features of the maxima of the graphs?

Comment: This is better know as site percolation http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SitePercolation.html .  The behaviour is similar to the better studied bond percolation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory.  There are papers on various graphs (not just "matrices").  I haven't looked into the finite case too much so can't suggest specific references.  I think you have the right idea (initially, as $p$ increases from $0$ you only have isolated points, each forming a cluster.  Thus the number of clusters increases linearly initially.  However, soon they start to merge.)

Comment: Note that for smaller graphs/matrices boundary effects are much stronger.  In particular, in an 8x8 matrix there are 28/64 "edge" sites (44%) vs 12% for 32x32 or 3% for 128x128.    These edge sites have fewer neighbours and thus intuitively more chance of being isolated.

Comment: I don't think there is a nice formula for the probably of a cluster with given size existing.  However, for large graphs/matrices, you can get some estimates for the size of the cluster containing a given site.